# How to create folder and copy into them with batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create .bat file for coping files in bin64. This works correctly when I copy in bin64 - existing folder, buth when I want to create folder in bin64 and copy in them files I have error. Can anybody help me?

```
copy "..\..\SCM\Path\Path\Data\Test.xml" "%OutputLocation%" - Works good
copy "..\..\SCM\Path\Path\Data\Test.xml" "%OutputLocation%\FeaturesAndRoles\" -Not good
```

Comment: You need to _first_ create the `FeaturesAndRoles` folder with the `md` command. Enter `md /?` for help...

Comment: Or use `XCopy`, where ending the destination directory with a trailing backslash will create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a batch file to create folder and copy files into it to multiple PCs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874308/using-a-batch-file-to-create-folder-and-copy-files-into-it-to-multiple-pcs)

Comment: Or `robocopy` which is the new xcopy :]